# Using + to check if multiple pointers are all NULL

Tags: c, pointers, if-statement, null

Syntactically it makes sense (Although it looks like some other language, which I don't particularly enjoy), it can save a lot of typing and code space, but how bad is it?

```
if(p1 + (unsigned)p2 + (unsigned)p3 == NULL)
{
    // all pointers are NULL, exit
}
```

Using pointer arithmetic with a pointer rvalue, I don't see how it could give a false result (the entire expression to evaluate to NULL even though not all pointers are NULL), but I don't exactly know how much evilness this potentially hides, so is it bad to do this, not-common way of checking if plenty of pointers are all NULL?

Comment: Pretty sure addition isn't defined for a pair of pointer operands, only subtraction. Even if it was defined with integer-like behavior, it introduces a theoretical risk of wraparound back to `NULL` (using `|` would eliminate that at least). Is `!p1 && !p2 && !p3` unacceptably verbose?

Comment: You can subtract 2 pointers from each other (to determine the distance between them), but you can't add pointers together, and you can't OR them together, either.  You will have to type-cast the pointers to integers to do the kind of arithmetic you are looking for

Comment: Gah, I missed the type-casting I used in my crash-free test environment

Comment: Oh, hey, way to completely change the question!

Comment: @JohnBollinger I am sorry, now the question becomes a better question, otherwise it would just simply not compile, which in this case the question "is it bad" is totally absurd. I initially wanted to ask that, but forgot the type-casting. Sometimes I really need to copy-paste sometimes I better not.

Comment: But now with the casts "it can save a lot of typing and code space" is also totally absurd, isn't it?

Comment: @sebrockm fair point hahaha. Kinda looses that point

Comment: Casting to `unsigned` is liable to lose half the pointer, since `unsigned` can be 32-bit and a pointer 64-bit. So you could have a non-NULL pointer that ends up with the value 0 when cast to `unsigned`. In short, everything about this is absolutely horrible.

Comment: @user3386109 well one can type cast it with long long, but the results can be very well beyond that too, the matter is whether the expression can evaluate to 0 if it goes beyond the scope. If it does then the condition may fail, but in extremely rare cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple reasons why this is not a reliable method.

First, when you add an integer to a pointer, the C standard does not say what happens if the result is outside of the array into which the pointer points. (For these purposes, pointing just one past the last element, the end of the array, counts as inside, not outside. Also, a pointer to a single object counts as an array of one object.) Note that the C standard does not just not say what the **result** of the addition is; it does not say what the **behavior of the entire program** is. So, once you execute an addition that goes outside of an array, you cannot predict (from the C standard) what your program will do at all.

One likely result is that the compiler will see `pointer + integer + integer` and reason (or, more technically, apply transformations as if this reasoning were used) that `pointer + integer` is valid only if `pointer` is not `NULL`, and then the result is never `NULL`, so the expression `pointer + integer` is never `NULL`. Similarly, `pointer + integer + integer` is never `NULL`. Therefore `pointer + integer + integer == NULL` is always false, and we can optimize the program by removing this code completely. Thus, the code to handle the case when all pointers are `NULL` will be silently removed from your program.

Second, even if the C standard did guarantee a result of the addition, this expression could, hypothetically, evaluate to `NULL` even if none of the pointers were `NULL`.  For example, consider a 16-bit address space where the first pointer were represented with the address 0x7000, the second were 0x6000, and the third were 0x3000. (I will also suppose these are `char *` pointers, so one element is one byte.) If we add these, the mathematical result is 0x10000. In 16-bit arithmetic, that wraps, so the computed result is 0x0000. Thus, the expression could evaluate to zero, which is likely used for `NULL`.

Third, `unsigned` may be narrower than pointers (for example, it may be 32 bits while pointers are 64), so the cast may lose information—there may be non-zero bits in the bits that were lost during the conversion, so the test will fail to detect them.

There are situations where we want to optimize pointer tests, and there are legitimate but non-standard ways to do it. On some processors, branching can be expensive, so doing some arithmetic with one test and one branch may be faster than doing three tests and three branches. C provides an integer type intended for working with pointer representations:  `uintptr_t`, declared in `<stdint.h>`. With that, we can write this code:

```
if (((uintptr_t) p1 | (uintptr_t) p2 | (uintptr_t) p3) == 0) …
```

What this does is convert each pointer to an unsigned integer of a width suitable for working with pointer representations. The C standard does not say what the result of this conversion is, but it is intended to be unsurprising, and C implementations for flat address spaces may document that the result is the memory address. They may also document that `NULL` is the zero address. Once we have these integers, we OR them together instead of adding them. The result of an OR has a bit set if either of the corresponding bits in its operands was set. Thus, if any one of the addresses is not zero, then the result will not be zero either. So this code, if executed in a suitable C implementation, will perform the test you desire.

(I have used such tests in special high-performance code to test whether all pointers were aligned as desired, rather than to test for `NULL`. In that case, I had direct access to the compiler developers and could ensure the compiler would behave as desired. This is **not** standard C code.)

Comment: I see, I also tested this idea and for me it worked 50000 times in a loop, but as you say there is no reason to think this will be always the case.

Comment: Very interesting and enlightening. Those were two very useful answers.

Comment: I am a big fan of optimizational programming.
And I never thought of `if ((uintptr_t) p1 | (uintptr_t) p2 | (uintptr_t) p3 == 0)` so this is like christmas present answer to me.

Comment: Although I am really surprised that this is faster considering that converting values is usually a very slow task for the compiler.

Comment: @Edenia: Casting between types with identical width is typically *zero* work at runtime (the cost at compile time is meaningless in the context of everything else). The bit representation doesn't change here; the cast performs literally no work at all besides telling the compiler that integer-like operations are allowed.

Comment: @Edenia: Note that I edited that code to insert more parentheses—the `|` operator has lower precedence than `==`, so the OR operations must be enclosed in parentheses. And remember, this is only valid in C implementations that define the result of pointer conversions suitably; it is not standard C. And you will not notice much performance different except when the tests appear in performance-critical code, particularly in loops executed a great many times.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I know, I started programming in an old SDL-based platform for game creation that used EiC interpreter. There you have FPS restriction, therefore it was performance-critical. Also I occasionally program 16 Mhz processors

Comment: @ShadowRanger I see. I reasoned like that, because I know float-integer conversions are in fact, really slow.

Comment: @Edenia: Yes, floating point is typically a whole different suite of registers, and the bit representations are barely related. By contrast, at least on x86/x86-64, pointers and identically sized integers are stored in the same register type, and casting between identically sized pointers and integer types is purely about code logic, not operation. If a pointer is stored in `%rax`, and you cast it to `uintptr_t` for an operation, all that does is allow you to do integer math with it without getting warnings, it still uses `%rax` unmodified. There's no difference from an assembly point of view.

Answer (score 5):

Regarding to the original version of the question, which omitted the casts ...

> it can save a lot of typing and code space, but how bad is it?

Very, very bad.  Its behavior is altogether undefined, and if your compiler fails to reject it then you should get yourself a better one.  Subtraction of one pointer from another is defined under some circumstances (and yields an integer result), but it is never meaningful to *add* two pointers.

Inasmuch as it shouldn't even compile, every keystroke used to type it instead of something that works is wasted, so no, it doesn't save typing or code space.

> I don't see how it could give a false result.

If the compiler actually accepts it, the result can be anything at all.  It is **undefined**.

> so is it bad to do this, not-common way of checking if plenty of pointers are all NULL?

Yes.

---

Regarding the modified question in which all but one of the pointers are cast to integer:

The casts do not rescue the code -- multiple problems remain.

1. If the remaining pointer does not point to a valid object, or if the sum of the integers is negative or greater than the number of elements in the array to which the pointer points then the result of the pointer addition is still undefined (where a pointer to a scalar is treated as a pointer to a one-element array).  Of course, the integer sum can't be negative in this particular case, but that's of minimal advantage.
2. C does not guarantee that casting a null pointer to an integer yields the value 0.  It is common for it to do so, but the language does not require it.
3. C does not guarantee that non-null pointers convert to nonzero integers, and with your particular code that's a genuine risk.  The type `unsigned` is not necessarily large enough to afford a distinct value to every distinct pointer.
4. Even if all of the foregoing were not a problem for some particular implementation -- that is, if you could safely perform arithmetic on a NULL pointer, and NULL pointers reliably converted to integers as zero, and non-NULL pointers reliably converted to nonzero -- the test could *still* go wrong because two nonzero unsigned integers can sum to zero.  That happens where the arithmetic sum of the two is equal to `UINT_MAX + 1`.

Comment: Yes, @Edenia, you were, but if you give me a moment I'll address the revised question too.

Comment: I feel bad now, if you want you can leave what you have wrote and I will edit my question with a follow-up question that relates to your initial answer. (but you may have to clarify that it responds to my follow-up question)

Comment: Well, @Edenia, although we do strongly prefer that you not make such impactful changes to a question after positing it, I think it would be best to avoid posting a second question on this topic.  Don't feel badly; just do better next time.  And consider my revised comments.

Answer (score 0):

Using any sort of pointer arithmetic on non-array pointers is undefined behavior in C.

Comment: No.  Pointer arithmetic on a pointer to a scalar is, according to the standard, handled as if the pointer pointed to a single-element array.

Comment: Fair point.  I should have clarified it a little more however this is more defined as an exception to make some specific pointer arithmetic work.

Comment: I'd say rather that the standard acknowledges that there is no way to distinguish via a pointer whether the pointed-to object is an element of an array, and there's no particular reason to make such a distinction.  Exactly opposite to your claim, in fact.